# Expressing computer time units with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I need to express things like (longhand) 'this fullword contains the elapsed time in units of 1048576 microseconds'.

I would imagine something like '... units of µs × 2²° ...' (horrid superscript, I know) might be an adequate shorthand, and thought of `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
    binary-units=true,
    prefixes-as-symbols=false,
    ]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
%In units of \si{\mebi\micro\second}. % <= Fails

In units of \si{\mebi\bit}.

In units of \si{\mebi\second}.

In units of \SI{1}{\mebi\second}
\end{document}
```

It appears that siunitx, reasonably,  won't let me mix prefixes:

```
! siunitx error: "prefix-base-mismatch"
! 
! Prefix bases do not match.
```

Can anyone suggest an adequate notation, and how I might achieve it in siunitx?

Comment: What's wrong with '`in units of \SI[parse-numbers = false]{2^{20}}{\micro\second}`'?

Comment: How about `\DeclareSIUnit{\microsecond}{\ensuremath{\mu}s} \si{\mebi\microsecond}`?

Comment: @JosephWright: Nothing. An excellent suggestion!

Comment: @Jake: I like that slightly better than Joseph's, as it gives me the flexibility of producing 'Miµs' (as in mimsy). If you'd like to make that an answer, it's got a good chance. After Joseph has had another opportunity to comment.

Comment: @Jake That will use the wrong symbol for micro (italic rather than upright by default). If you want to go this way, use `\SIUnitSymbolMicro` rather than `\ensuremath{\mu}`.

Comment: @JosephWright: Ah, thank you! I was wondering how to do that, but all the options I found for getting upright greek letters seemed a bit too involved for such a simple task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\microsecond}{\SIUnitSymbolMicro s} \si{\mebi\microsecond}
```

which allows you to type

```
In units of \si{\mebi\microsecond}.
```

to get

[image]

Comment: "Prefixes may not be used in combination." - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix . "mebi (megabinary)" (a number) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebi-#IEC_standard_prefixes . I would write : _In_units_of_mebi_us_  (u=$\mu$)

Comment: Just to clarify: I think that `Mi` is a prefix, while `mebi` is a number. `\mu` is a prefix. You are not allowed to use two prefixes in combination. Of cause `mebi \mu s` still needs to be declared in `siunitx` somehow.